# Multiple bibliographies in one document showing different fields

Tags: biblatex, environments

I'm using biblatex (backend biber) to generate the bibliography in my PDF. In particular, I have two bibliographies, one regular numeric and one with a dedicated bib environment. Now I would like to show the `notes` field for entries in the specific bibliography, and hide the `notes` field in the regular bibliography. Now my problem is that I don't know how to use different field sets for two different bibliographies. Can I do this using the environment? Two different `bibstyle` settings are not possible, as far as I know.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, sorting=nty, maxnames=99, firstinits=true, 
 backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{midbib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%\bibhang
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{knuth1986texbook,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bibby, D.},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@article{knuth1977fast,
  title={Fast pattern matching in strings},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Morris Jr, J.H. and Pratt, V.R.},
  journal={SIAM journal on computing},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={323--350},
  year={1977},
  publisher={SIAM},
  Keywords={specific},
  notes = {This is an example of extensive notes.}
}
@inproceedings{knuth1970simple,
  title={Simple word problems in universal algebras},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bendix, P.B.},
  booktitle={Computational problems in abstract algebra},
  volume={263},
  pages={297},
  year={1970}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
After the following lines, the specific bibliography is printed. For every entry in this bibliography I would like to show the notes field~\cite{knuth1986texbook, knuth1977fast, knuth1970simple}.
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=specific, sorting=none, env=midbib]

\section{Regular bibliography}
In this regular bibliography, I would like to hide the notes field.
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the use of the `biblatex` package mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the field is `note` not `notes`. You can delete the field at the begin of the bib:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, sorting=nty, maxnames=99, firstinits=true,
 backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{midbib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%\bibhang
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\addbibresource{references.bib}

\newbool{killnote}

\AtEveryBibitem{\ifbool{killnote}{\clearfield{note}}{}}

\begin{document}
After the following lines, the specific bibliography is printed. For every entry in this bibliography I would like to show the notes field~\cite{knuth1986texbook, knuth1977fast, knuth1970simple}.

\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=specific, sorting=none, env=midbib]

\section{Regular bibliography}
In this regular bibliography, I would like to hide the notes field.

\booltrue{killnote}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]